# Do I have a backend issue if I my Phonon SeekSlider isn't working?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, phonon

I'm currently developing a GUI software package, written in Python (3.4) utilising the Qt framework (PySide).

This current development is on a Windows 7 platform (64-bit).

At present, the SeekSlider is successfully linked to the Video MediaObject, such that the slider will progress as the video plays. However, I am unable to manually change the playback position of the video by moving the seekslider with the mouse. The seekslider 'handle' is greyed out, so I'm unable to grab it.

The code I've written is posted below; it's worth mentioning that I've used the exact same code on a similar software suite written/executed under a Linux system (Ubuntu 14.04), and the SeekSlider worked exactly as expected. As such, I can only image that the Phonon backend under Windows 7 is causing the issue.

Another point to note: I'm also using a VolumeSlider, which is working perfectly under Windows 7.

```
#Phonon MediaObject
self.Player = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
self.Player.setTickInterval(10)

#Phonon Audio
self.Audio = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory, self.PlaybackContainer)

#Phonon Video Widget
self.PlaybackWidget = Phonon.VideoWidget(self.PlaybackContainer)

#Creating Path and Setting Source
Phonon.createPath(self.Player, self.Audio)
Phonon.createPath(self.Player, self.PlaybackWidget)
self.Player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource("Videos/Playback.asf"))

#Playback Controls#
self.SeekSlider = Phonon.SeekSlider(self.Player, self.PlaybackContainerMain)
self.VolumeSlider = Phonon.VolumeSlider(self.Audio, self.PlaybackContainerMain)
```

I've omitted some of the formatting code to keep the above clean and simple.

Given that the above exact code functions perfectly under Linux, is a possible Windows backend issue the likely problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. As far as I recall there are some phonon examples packaged with PySide. (https://github.com/PySide/Examples/tree/master/examples/phonon or in the folder of your PySide installation) Could you try them and find out if their seek slider works?